# flutter Firestore where query not displaying when using variable values

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

in flutter Firestore the `where` query is not displaying the values when using a variable.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Schedules')
        .where('from', isEqualTo: widget.from)
        .where('to', isEqualTo: widget.to)
        .snapshots();
```

when i tried to call it with specified value it displays the items.

```
.where('from', isEqualTo: "Ethiopia")
```

[Firestore data structure is here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaGin.jpg)

how can i fix such problem?

Comment: It sounds like the `widget.from` and `widget.to` don't have the values you expect. You might want to place a breakpoint ont he query, run iin a debugger, and check the values.

Comment: i used it in a text widget and it has a value... although if it helps i'm using this inside a stream builder.

Comment: Without seeing the values of those variables, and how they match the documents in your database, there's not much we can do to help.  Consider hard coding your filer values and try again.  If it doesn't work the way you expect, show that new code and explain how the result doesn't match.

Comment: initially there is a variable `from` and `to`. these will store the users input data. So when i call this variables in other class i used `widget.from` & `widget.to` and also there is a database field `from` & `to`. that's why i used `where('from', isEqualTo: widget.from)` in my code. there is my database structure above

Answer (score 1):

Posting as Community Wiki, based in the comments.

The issue here is within the variables that you are trying to compare the values - `widget.to` and `widget.from` - as the `where` clause works. You will need to change the way you are passing this variables in the `where` part of the query, so you have the certain, that the values are being passed correctly, as right now, this is the issue.

I would recommend you to change the way you are checking the values, so it's confirmed that the variables have the values in the needed context.

Comment: i used `widget.to` & `widget.from` in a text widget to display the values, it works. but when i try to use it in where query its not displaying anything.

Comment: Hi @MoBix sure, I understand that. However, these are different things. Have you tried using different variables, confirmed the context for the variable when doing the query, etc.?

Comment: can you show me an example how to do that? my app does a drop down form which a user selects from and pass those data to the next page (which is this firestore page). so how can i do this?

Comment: Hi @MoBix it could be any simple test like `var from = widget.from`, just to perform a different way of querying, for example, you can try also changing the `isEqualTo` for `==`. Please, also bear in mind that, SO is not mean to provide you the solution or code for you, but to help you achieve the solution, so, the Community won't, necessarily, be providing you the code to fix your issue.

Comment: i tried passing those variables in to another variable. it still is not recognizing the `widget` in `var from = widget.from`. i even tried using it with `initState`.

Comment: Hi @MoBix so, this just confirms that the value is not being well send from a page into another and this way, the query doesn't work. Please, change the way you are transfering your data, to try a different approach.

Comment: but it is working with a text widget.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. However, bear in mind that it works for a text in a wdiget and as far as I understand, in the page previous to the one where the data is used for the query, so, they are completely different parts of the application - besides the fact that one is a wdiget and the other one is a function of querying of a third-party application. Please, change the way you are sending the data, so the variable has the value in the destination page, so the query will work.

Comment: thanks a lot. i kinda got the idea